# Django Rest Framework, group_by queries using .values(), and embedding a related record

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I can't figure out how to embed a related record into a Django Rest Framework response when using .values() on a Django query set to return grouped by aggregated values. Sample Models, Serializers, and Viewset included below along with current response and a sample desired response.

Each Trade has one security. Multiple trades can exist for a security. I have a need to display Trades individually and also grouped by security. When grouping by security, I want to return the embedded security in the response along with the aggregate values for the associated trades, but so far I can only get the security id returned. Any attempt to get the security itself in the response results in an exception `'int' object has no attribute 'pk'`

Trade model

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    security = models.ForeignKey('Security')
    ticker = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    shares = models.FloatField(db_index=True)
    value_usd = models.FloatField(db_index=True)
    days_to_trade = models.FloatField(db_index=True)
    trade_date = models.DateField(
        db_index=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Security model

```
class Security(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        db_index=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    ipo_date = models.DateField(
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

Trade View

```
class TradeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        // param and filter setup/defaults snipped for clarity
        ...
        qs = Trade.objects.filter(**qs_filter)
        // if group_by param is passed in, then group the trades by ticker/security and return aggregate sums for value, shares, and days to trade
        if group_by:
            qs = qs.values('ticker', 'security_id').annotate(value_usd=Sum('value_usd'), shares=Sum('shares'), days_to_trade=Sum('days_to_trade'), num_trades=Count('security')).order_by('ticker')
            self.serializer_class = TradeByTickerSerializer
        return qs

    serializer_class = TradeSerializer
```

Trade serializer

```
class TradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    security = SecuritySerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = [
            'id',
            'security',
            'trade_date',
            'ticker',
            'shares',
            'value_usd',
            'days_to_trade',
        ]
        depth = 1
```

TradeByTicker serializer

```
class TradeByTickerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    num_trades = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    // security = SecuritySerializer(many=False, read_only=True) // this gives an exception 
    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = [
            // 'security', // I tried this but get an exception
            'security_id',
            'ticker',
            'shares',
            'value_usd',
            'days_to_trade',
            'num_trades',
        ]
```

Current output

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "securityId": 123,
            "ticker": "ABC-US",
            "shares": 790611.154356048,
            "valueUsd": 15598758.0754448,
            "daysToTrade": 7.2460672754406,
            "numTrades": 1
        },
        {
            "securityId": 456,
            "ticker": "DEF-US",
            "shares": 1116548.93406872,
            "valueUsd": 29041437.7751273,
            "daysToTrade": 6.6811609336384,
            "numTrades": 3
        },
        {
            "securityId": 789,
            "ticker": "HIJ-US",
            "shares": 979099.946772097,
            "valueUsd": 16360760.1105617,
            "daysToTrade": 6.50616625094424,
            "numTrades": 2
        },
        ...
]
```

Desired output

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "security": {
                "id": 123,
                "name": "Another Boring Company",
                "ipoDate": "1988-12-23"
            },
            "ticker": "ABC",
            "shares": 790611.154356048,
            "valueUsd": 15598758.0754448,
            "daysToTrade": 7.2460672754406,
            "numTrades": 1
        },
        {
            "security": {
                "id": 456,
                "name": "Def Jam Records",
                "ipoDate": "2001-04-24"
            },
            "ticker": "DEF",
            "shares": 1116548.93406872,
            "valueUsd": 29041437.7751273,
            "daysToTrade": 6.6811609336384,
            "numTrades": 3
        },
        {
            "security": {
                "id": 789,
                "name": "Hijinx Corp",
                "ipoDate": "1999-12-31"
            },
            "ticker": "HIJ",
            "shares": 979099.946772097,
            "valueUsd": 16360760.1105617,
            "daysToTrade": 6.50616625094424,
            "numTrades": 2
        },
        ...
]
```

Comment: Can you also show `ProjectedTrade`?

Comment: ProjectedTrade was supposed to be Trade... copy/paste error fixed.

Comment: Ah I get it now. This is a tricky one, because grouping them like this causes your queryset to not return `Trade` objects anymore, which the serializer requires. Let me see if there's a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `SerializerMethodField` to handle getting the related security details like this:

```
class TradeByTickerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    num_trades = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    security = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = [
            'security',
            'security_id',
            'ticker',
            'shares',
            'value_usd',
            'days_to_trade',
            'num_trades',
        ]

    def get_security(self, obj)
        return SecuritySerializer(Security.objects.get(pk=obj['security_id'])).data
```

Or since the queryset does not containt `Trade` objects anymore, I would suggest to just use `Serializer` (non-`ModelSerializer`):

```
class TradeByTickerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    security = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ticker = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)
    shares = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)
    value_usd = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)
    days_to_trade = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)
    num_trades = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    def get_security(self, obj)
        return SecuritySerializer(Security.objects.get(pk=obj['security_id'])).data
```

Note though that this will hit the database per result of the group by queryset, just to fetch the related `Security` object.